# Different passwords for different folders in shared drive. How?

Tags: windows, encryption, password-manager, directories

We have a PC as server and shared drive. Other PCs access this shared drive to read/write files/folders. Let's say there are 5 Main folders in this shared drive, named F1 to F5, which belong to PC1 to PC5 respectively.

We want to set different passwords for different folders. So that different PCs can access their own files/folders at the same time.

I tried some software, but unfortunately, they set one password for all the folders that I specify.

Would you please recommend a software that can set different passwords for different folders in windows?

P.S. I don't want to compress the files/folders. So compression software like WinRar are not of use in this case.

***Update***

I tried a software called "Folder Guard". I was able to set different passwords for different folders. But the problem is that when setting paswords for shared folders, the other people on the network could not access those folders (access denied)!

Comment: Any suggestions ???

Comment: Usernames and passwords are pairs.  However, you can create multiple usernames and assign each user to a different folder, and therefore will have a different password.

Comment: Thanks @cybernard for your comment. But that won't help. Because I want to share these folders in a server.

Comment: any other suggestions?

Comment: You could use junctions or links, the **mklink** command to link them into 1 folder and share that.  So //server/shareme/a,//server/shareme/b //server/shareme/c.  However inside the shareme folde a,b,and c would be junctions,hard link, or symlinks to another location.

Comment: Compression programs can store files without any compression, still performing a strong encryption with a per-file password. I won't discard those too quickly.

Comment: Thanks @cybernard for your comment. Actually, what I need is a simple password manager software, that sets passwords for each folder.

Comment: Thanks @Alejandro for your comment. I tried the store option of these compression softwares. It doesn't work for me, because it finally changes files/folders to e.g. RAR formats. What I want is to keep the format (folder or file), and only set password, so that anyone attempting to open the folder/file, shall provide password.

Comment: If the idea is to keep other people out of your personal files, why not simply use the OS built-in permissions system? Use a different user account for each person, so that their account don't have permission to view your files. Just put a good password on your user account and block the computer when away.

Comment: @Alejandro, The idea is to have a PC as a shared server, where all the files are stored and read/written. The other PCs connect to shared PC, and see e.g. 5 folders, named e.g. PC1 to PC5. Each PC accesses its own folder by password. Since all the PCs might want to access their folders at the same time, the username idea would not work here.

Comment: By using standard file sharing techniques, that is using a normal file access (not a remote desktop) each computer is asked for a user/password, and only granted access according to its permissions. That's the exact problem the permission system of pretty much any curren OS solves. Can you update the question with this very relevant data? Now it's clear to me that we have a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). You don't need any software, you need to learn how to configure and use your OS for doing what you want.

Comment: @Alejandro, I edited the main post. However, as I indicated, I don't want to configure the OS. It is simple: I want to set different passwords for different folders. That's it.

Comment: @Alejandro; Well, I found a software called Folder Guard. It works pretty well. Different passwords and protection levels for different folders. So far so good!

Comment: @cybernard; Well, I found a software called Folder Guard. It works pretty well. Different passwords and protection levels for different folders. So far so good!

Comment: @Omid1989 Is there a reason not to use permissions and password protect/encrypt the computer with the hardware drive?

Comment: @Janekmuric, There are 2 main reasons: (1) This main PC is not just for keeping files as server; it has an operator itself, like other PCs, working with programs, etc. (2) The other PCs may want to access the files in shared drive at the same time.

Comment: @Omid1989 So you want to encrypt to folders? There is no other way to secure them. Pull encryped file from drive -> decrypt -> Modify -> Encrypt -> Push file to drive -> Repeat. A script could be built to automate this so you copy a file to a local folder and the script auto-encrypts and sends to the network drive. This is nice, however the key would have to be stored locally. And since you seem to be in a security-sensitive enviroment that wouldn not be recommended.

Comment: @Janekmuric, There's no need to encrypt. I just want to set passwords, so simple.

Comment: @Omid1989 This maybe :http://techvitalcomputer.blogspot.hr/2013/03/how-to-share-folder-on-network-with-password-protection.html?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into Encryption Software, there is plenty of software can protect, lock and Encrypt shared folders.

Try Folder Lock [Folder Lock Information](http://www.newsoftwares.net/folderlock/)

Lock files, folders & drives
Encrypt files & folders
Backup files to a secure cloud
Protect USB/CD/Emails
Make Wallets
Shred files
Clean History

You can also check this link for more software recommendation [Encryption Software Info](http://encryption-software-review.toptenreviews.com/)